# Cannot find a 64 Byte Memory Leak when applying a filter in NSImage

Tags: swift, macos, memory-leaks, nsimage, swift4.2

Environment:

- Xcode 10.2
- Swift 4.2
- MacOS Target: 10.11

I have the following extension to NSImage:

```
extension NSImage {

    func filter(filter: String) -> NSImage? {
        return autoreleasepool { [weak self] () -> NSImage? in
            let image = CIImage(data: (self?.tiffRepresentation!)!)

            if let filter = CIFilter(name: filter) {
                filter.setDefaults()
                filter.setValue(image, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

                let context = CIContext(options: [CIContextOption.useSoftwareRenderer: true])
                // *** 64 Byte MEMORY LEAK on line below ***
                guard let imageRef = context.createCGImage(filter.outputImage!, from: image!.extent) else {
                    context.clearCaches()
                    context.reclaimResources()
                    return nil
                }
                context.clearCaches()
                context.reclaimResources()
                return NSImage(cgImage: imageRef, size: NSSize(width: 0, height: 0))
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }

}
```

The image being inverted is set in the InterfaceBuilder and is a 16KB 480x480 png with an alpha channel and sRGB IEC61966-2.1 color profile.  I am calling the "filter" function from a **subclassed NSButton** as follows:

```
...

override func awakeFromNib() {
    ....
    autoreleasepool {
        image = image!.filter(filter: "CIColorInvert")
    }
    ....
}
...
```

The filter works as advertised.  However, I am getting a 64 Byte memory leak at the guarded '**context.createCGImage**' call.

The things I have tried:

- Moving the autoreleasepool block up and down the filter function
- Removing the autoreleasepool block from the subclassed NSButton
- Removing one and both of the autoreleasepool blocks

Same results: 64 Byte Malloc memory leak at the line indicated above.  What am I missing?

Comment: Did you found a solution? This makes us crazyyy

Comment: Damn Apple doesn't release internal resources